# css background invalid property value for color

Tags: html, css

hi im pretty new to css and im having a probleem with a color value being wrong

```
article{
    float: left;
    width: 540px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left
    bottom, from(#94bae7), to(#FFF);
    background: -o-gradient(#94BAE7 , #FFF);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #94BAE7 0%, #FFF 100%);
}
```

Comment: Heres a more usefull tool for making background gradients: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - error prone as gradients are a though thing to do. Do it ther and copy, then you have guaranteed code that is as compatible as it gets.

Comment: ty so much this solved it. unfortunately no clue how it does it but that something i need to figure out myself :P

Comment: Im guessing the error is in the `from()` and `to()` values, I think the gradient site uses `#000000 0, #FFFFFF 100` (which defines two points, one at 0 and one at 100%, same thing, just not using words). Just compare their code to yours and it will become obvious, I guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one small ) - close bracket will cause you that problem in line background: -webkit-gradient.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#94bae7), to(#FFF));
```

After to(#FFF) use another close bracket.

Comment: excuse me while im banging my head against the wall ^^

Answer (score 0):

This should work, btw: padding: 0; is the same as padding: 0 0 0 0;

```
article {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #94bae7 , #FFF); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #94bae7, #FFF); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #94bae7, #FFF); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #94bae7 , #FFF);  
}
```